# unique constraint check not enforced

Tags: mysql, h2

```
create table A (id, field1, field2, field3, field4)
```

I have a `unique constraint on field1, field2, field3` and the following records are stored in the table

e.g.

```
insert into A (1, "f1", null, "f3", "f4");
insert into A (2, "f1", null, "f3", "f4");
insert into A (3, "f1", null, "f3", "f4");
```

I would expect this to throw an unique constraint violation since all records are in violation, but it doesn't. What am I missing here, did check the database and the unique constraint index has been created.

Comment: Can you post a `show create table A` for us?  The statement you use there doesn't indicate data types.

Comment: assume, they are all string fields

Answer (score 4):

`Null` value is never equal to **any** other value, even `null` too. `null != null`

That is why record `a + null + b` will be never duplicate record `a + null + b`

Comment: how do I avoid enforce this constraint then, assuming field2 will contain value only under certain circumstances and rest of the times it will be a null value.

Comment: any chance you can set a `not null default '' `?

Comment: @Jason: i don't know any possible way to do that in mysql.

Comment: @Jason: http://db4free.blogspot.com/2006/01/emulating-check-constraints.html you can try this. Simple enough solution. It is a dirty hack, but it works ;-)

Comment: my app needs to run against multiple databases in dev/test modes, so database specific modifications aren't possible. They will have to be JPA model compliant